# if a thief steals items from a player but is also killed that night, where do the items go?

Tags: werewolv.es

If a thief steals my items and is then killed by someone, are the items with the killer or with the dead thief in the graveyard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heyo,

In that scenario, the items will stay with the thief and land in the Graveyard.